# Getting launcher activity class name

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

Is there a way to get the class name of the activity that launched the Intent without putting extras to the Intent?

I use the following code to launch other activities.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CallerClass.this, TargetClass.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Can I get the caller class' name in the target class?

Comment: No without setting extra, you can't get. If you use startActivityForResult then you will get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do it is by using [`startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) instead of [`startActivity(Intent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) and then have the second activity use [`getCallingActivity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCallingActivity%28%29) to get the `CallerClass`.

Answer (score 1):

use startActivityForResult then you can retrieve activity caller by : getCallingActivity().getClassName()

Answer (score 0):

```
String packageName = context.getPackageName();
Intent launchIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
String className = launchIntent.getComponent().getClassName();
```